# Display XML island

Tags: javascript, xml

I am using javascript with several XML islands. One of my islands is coming back null and it is when it is being loaded by another Island. I was hoping someone knew of a way to display what is in these islands. Everything is in a xhtml file with xslt files assisting it.

Island1.XMLDocument.loadXML( Island2.XMLDocument.xml );

Island1 is coming back null and I am just trying to find a way to verify what is in any of the islands even when there is good data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is Javascript in Internet Explorer, you could set a break point using the script debugger before the line in question and check the values. You could also insert a javascript alert to show you the Island2.XMLDocument.xml value.